# Batch: using upper for loop parameter in lower one

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

The command im trying to run is:

```
::%items% is defined elsewhere and is the amount of items per line in the file
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-%items% delims=," %%1 IN (`TYPE %TextFile%`) DO (

        FOR /l %%a in (%items%,-1,1) do (
            set /a "number=%%a"
            echo !number!

:: This is the main command I believe im having issues with
        set word!number!=%%!number!


        echo !word1!
        echo !word2!
        echo !word3!
    )
    set /a "lineused%randomline%=1"
    goto exitloop
)
:exitloop
pause
```

Now what I'm trying to do is set the variable called wordX where X is the number of the token. Edit: Basically, trying to use the %% variabla from the upper for loop which the lower one is running inside of.
I could type all the lines of

```
set word1=%%1
set word2=%%2
set word3=%%3
```

but that would defeat the purpose of the versatile system I'm trying to build.
Format of the text file (%TextFile%) would simply be, in this case:

```
line1i1,line1i2
line2i1,line2i2
```

But I need for it to work also on for example:

```
line1i1,line1i2,line1i3,line1i4
line2i1,line2i2,line2i3,line1i4
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea, but that cannot work because FOR variable expansion takes place *before* delayed expansion. You need a method to get an extra round of FOR variable expansion.

You can CALL a subroutine, and then use a dummy FOR loop to re-establish a FOR context. FOR variables are global in scope as long as you are in a FOR loop context. So your subroutine can access a FOR variable that was defined earlier.

```
...
...
    FOR /F "tokens=1-%items% delims=," %%1 IN ('TYPE %TextFile%') DO (

        FOR /l %%a in (%items%,-1,1) do call :set %%a

        echo !word1!
        echo !word2!
        echo !word3!
    )
...
...
exit /b

:set
for %%. in (.) do set "word%1=%%%1"
exit /b
```

The above works, but I don't like it because CALLs are expensive (slow). This is typically not a problem when you only have a few CALLs. But in this case the CALL is in a tight loop - one for every column times the number of rows in the file. Ouch!

If you really want to parametize your SET statements, and you want decent performance, then you can define a dynamic "macro". Simply store the needed commands in a variable, and then execute the content of the variable within your loop.

Also note that the above is limited to 9 items (10 if you start with 0 instead of 1). It is easy to extend the supported item count to 26 if you use letters, and a lookup string.

Finally, your dynamic FOR is within some parenthesized block. Presumably your ITEMS is defined outside the block, otherwise `%items%` could not be used in the FOR /F definition. The SET macro must be expanded using regular expansion, so it should be defined at the same time ITEMS is defined - outside the outer loop.

```
set /a items=3
::Define SET macro
set "v= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "set="
for /l %%N in (1 1 %items%) do set "set=!set!&set "word%%N=%%!v:~%%N,1!""
set "set=!set:~1!"

FOR ... some loop ... DO (
  ...
  ...

  FOR /F "tokens=1-%items% delims=," %%A IN ('TYPE %TextFile%') DO (
    %set%
    echo !word1!
    echo !word2!
    echo !word3!
  )

  ...
  ...
)
```

If the ITEMS variable must be set within the outer loop, then you must CALL out of the loop to establish the inner FOR /F loop.

Comment: If `items` is really defined in an outer `for` loop, you'll need felayed expansion in the inner `for /L` loop (your 2nd approach)...

Comment: @aschipfl - Yeah, I think this simply confirms there is something odd with my brain :-) I'm also a musician, and a while back I woke up with a song in my head that features a 19/8 rhythmic cycle. http://soundcloud.com/dave-benham/dave-benham-trio-dance-of-the-crane

Answer (score 0):

*Note that you dont need the `TYPE` to get contents of file, the `FOR` command itself can iterate over file content*

You could try something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "TextFile=textfile.txt"
set /a "lineNum=0"
set /a "i=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%TextFile%) do (
        set /a lineNum=!line_num! + 1
        set "line=%%a"
        for %%b in ("!line:,=" "!") do (
            set /a "i=!i!+1"
            set /a "wordNum=!lineNum! * !i!
            set "word!wordNum!=%%b"
    )
)
echo !word1!
echo !word2!
echo !word3!
```

Given a file with the contents:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
eee,fff,ggg,hhh
```

Output will be:

```
"aaa"
"bbb"
... and so on
```

To remove the quotes, use `%%~b` at the inner FOR at `set "word!wordNum!` line.

Also note that you don't even need to define the number of items per line!

Hope it helps,
Cheers!

Comment: This could work in many situations, but it will fail if any line contains `*`, `?`, or `"` characters.